# Visual studio 2012 msi setup does not update .exe file in newer version

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-installer, exe, setup-project

I am building a setup in VS2012 - installshield.
I have to upgrade the version of my application and create a new installer.

I changed the product version and update the version of my application and setup too. (they where 2.0.2.0 now are 2.0.3.0).

The installation works correctly and the updates seem to work (2.0.2.0 does not exist anymore and 2.0.3.0 is installed) but it happens that myapplication.exe after the msi is launched is erased!

Only if I run the msi another time in repair mode the .exe is added.
I would like that the installation will  keep the exe without this boring second step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question.
I naively just forgot to set the compile mode from debug to release; so the compilation worked but I had this side effect.